# Working with the definition of periodic function

Tags: mathematics, crystals

I'm exploring periodic conditions and I'm stuck in a problem. Given that $m\cdot L_1 = n \cdot L_2$, we have two periodic functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ with periods $L_1$ and $L_2$ where we can find, for example that $f_1(x+m\cdot L_1) = f_1(x)$. What can I say about the period of the sum of these two functions? If I use the defition of a periodic funcion $f(x+L) = f(x)$ then i have $f_1(x+m\cdot L_1)$ + $f_2(x+n\cdot L_2)$ =  $f_1(x)$ + $f_1(x)$. But, what about the new period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are periodic functions with periods $L_1$ and $L_2$, then, by definition, $f_1(x+L_1) = f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x+L_2) = f_2(x)$. If you've expressed yourself clearly, you're interested in the periodicity properties of $f(x) = f_1(x)+f_2(x)$ for the case where there exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that $mL_1 = n_L2$.

For this case, if you define $L=mL_1=nL_2$, then both components will satisfy
$$
f_1(x+L) = f_1 (x+m L_1) = f_1(x)
$$
(and similarly for $f_2(x)$), so you'll have $f(x+L) = f(x)$, and it is accurate to say that $f(x)$ is $L$-periodic.

However, it is conceivable that $f(x)$ will have a shorter period than $L$. If you want to rule this out, then it is necessary and sufficient to require that $m$ and $n$ be [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers), i.e., that they do not share any prime factors. If they do, then they will have a nontrivial common divisor $k$, and $L/k$ will also preserve $f(x)$. The minimal period of $f(x)$ is then given by the greatest common divisor (gcd) of $m$ and $n$.